# Having trouble with a frequency to voltage converter for universal frequency input

Tags: wiring, converter

I'm having trouble with a frequency converter. The [data sheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Phoenix%20Contact%20PDFs/2902056_Ds.pdf) is given here.

I set the converter for universal frequency input and voltage output. These can be configured by DIP switches. The diagram from the data sheet is given as below:

[image]

And here is how I do the wiring:

[image]

I use a 12V power supply, and as an input I couple 0/10V pulse train by using a function generator to the terminals 2 and 3 above. The pulse train is exactly 0..10V and I followed the advice on section 8.7 at page 20 to set the pulse properly.

I checked the DIP configuration too many times and I'm wondering whether my wiring is wrong. Just to make sure here is my DIP config:

For SW1: ON ON OFF OFF ON ON

For SW2: OFF ON OFF OFF OFF ON OFF ON OFF OFF

According to the data-sheet if I configure the DIP switches as above I should get 0 to 5V voltage output mapped from 1Hz to 300Hz frequency input range from a pulse train input.

But I get a constant 17.6V output by the voltmeter whatever the input frequency is, it is constant even though I don't hook up any input. The RED indicator flashes with 2.8Hz which data sheet says(at page 21) it happens when the "Sensor fault or invalid DIP switch configuration".

I spent several hours but no luck. Is the connection from the function generator to the terminals 2 and 3 correct?

Comment: 2-3 looks like a *switch closure*, not a voltage.

Comment: 2-3  terminals are named as universal freq with pulse train sign. I thought that's the input for a pulse train. How could I make use of this if I want to convert an incoming pulse train by using this converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For SW1: ON ON OFF OFF ON ON

You have configured "Universal Input Frequency to 0-5V". That's a relay input.
I'd would have used PNP input, but the manual is definitely not clear on this.
*(as expected from Phoenix Contact)*

> For SW2: OFF ON OFF OFF OFF ON OFF ON OFF **OFF**

1 to 300 hz, software configuration active.

You've set all the DIP switches, but you've forgot to enable dip 10, enabling the dip switches as active configuration.

---

New info from comment. With this sensor (Adolf Thies 4.3351.00.000) the output is push-pull. Similar to the function generator. However, you need to change the range significantly for 1082 Hz at 50 m/s (22 Hz per m/s)
Try DIP2: [ON ON] [OFF ON ON ON ON OFF] [OFF ON]
*10 Hz to 1200 Hz DIP configured, 10 Hz is 1 BFT, 1200 Hz is beyond 12 BFT*

Comment: Oh thanks I see you are right. I had to enable by pin 10. Thanks. And if I have a pulse train as input what would be a better option. I will actually use this sensor as input https://www.biral.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/firstclassWSanalog.pdf It says it has push pull output and open drain.

Comment: Yes 0 to 300Hz was for example. Thanks. But Im still confused whether terminal 2 3 for pulse input or relay input because it mentions on section 8.7 at page 20 to set the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

If Joroen's answer doesn't solve the problem I note that there is a app to configure certain options.

Page 1, Description states:

> You can optionally configure the device using DIP switches,
>   or with enhanced functionality via the S-PORT using the
>   standard Analog-Conf software via FDT/DTM, or without
>   further accessories using the Mini Analog Pro Smartphone
>   app.

Page 20 states:

> **8.7 Frequency input threshold**
>
> For universal frequency input a measuring threshold must
>   be employed.
>
> The measuring threshold should be in the center of the
>   frequency signal's amplitude.
>
> When measuring, ensure that all negative components of
>   the signal are cut. You must therefore place the measuring
>   threshold exactly in the center of the positive part of the
>   amplitude.

It seems to me that you may have to set your threshold to 5 V to detect your 0 to 10 V signal correctly. (But I don't know!)